# Adding Field Manually in DJango Form

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms

I am making a login-signup system in django, I want the Data of My Forms to Save in The in-built "User" table and my custom made "coders" table together. My Form Has 6-7 fields which i want to insert in custom "coders" table. but I want only to insert "username" and "password" in "User" table. I cant figure out how i can separate "username" and "password" from "FORM" . Here is My Code

```
def f1(request):
    form = codersform()
    form2 = User()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = codersform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            form2 = coders.objects.filter('name', 'pasw')#Getting Error
            form2.save()#in these two part
            user = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            messages.success(
                request, "Account Created Successfully For " + user)
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Please Fill Out All Fields Correctly")
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Form Code

```
<form action="" method="POST"  class="register-form" id="register-form">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
                                {{form.name}}
                                                                       
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="matid"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account-box"></i></label>
                                {{form.matid}}
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="phone"><i class="zmdi zmdi-phone"></i></label>
                                {{form.phone}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Semester"><i class="zmdi zmdi-star"></i></label>
                                {{form.semester}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Cf"><i class="zmdi zmdi-code"></i></label>
                                {{form.Cf}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label>
                                {{form.email}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label>
                                {{form.pasw}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="agree-term" id="agree-term" class="agree-term" />
                                <label for="agree-term" class="label-agree-term"><span><span></span></span>I agree all statements in  <a href="#" class="term-service">Terms of service</a></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-button">
                                <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" class="form-submit" value="Register"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant see username field in form fields, maybe you use name for username..

to create User object you need to provide all mandatory fields of User object

Try this modified code:

```
def f1(request):
form = codersform()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = codersform(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid:
        form.save()   
        User.objects.create(username=form.cleaned_data['name'],password=form.cleaned_data['pasw']
            messages.success(
                request, "Account Created Successfully For " + user)
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Please Fill Out All Fields Correctly")
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: welcome my brother and thank for up voting